# Kotlin coroutines. Unconfined dispatcher - concrete use cases?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Kotlin docs mention [unconfined dispatcher](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutine-context-and-dispatchers.html#unconfined-vs-confined-dispatcher).

Well, it is quite clear - an execution is not confined to a particular thread.

We see 2 passages

> The unconfined dispatcher is an advanced mechanism that can be helpful in certain corner cases where dispatching of a coroutine for its execution later is not needed or produces undesirable side-effects, because some operation in a coroutine must be performed right away. The unconfined dispatcher should not be used in general code.

> Unconfined dispatcher is appropriate when coroutine does not consume CPU time nor updates any shared data (like UI) that is confined to a specific thread.

those sound very abstract.

Question: Could anyone give 1-2-3 concrete use cases when you used this type of dispatcher? What are those "corner cases"? Even quite a good book "Kotlin Coroutines by Tutorials" skips details on this topic.

Thanks

Comment: From the performance point of view, `Dispatchers.Unconfined` dispatcher is the cheapest as it never requires thread switching. So, we might choose it if we do not care at all on which thread our code is running. However, in practice, it is not considered good to use it so recklessly. If by accident we miss a blocking call and we are running on the Main thread, this could lead to blocking the entire application.

Comment: @Sergey, hi, do you know why they talk about `updates any shared data`? is it smth analogous to "ThreadLocal" data in old java api? some data attached to particular execution thread? what do they mean by that?

Comment: I guess it's maybe because of the race condition.

Comment: I've used in in `Flow.stateIn()`, since the setter of `MutableStateFlow.value` should be thread safe it doesn't matter which dispatcher is being used to set it. I hope I'm correct, but it seems to work as expected: https://pl.kotl.in/lV38rxwWN